# Certain Subset of a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Does there exist an infinite ring $R$ with finitely many units and an infinite $S \subseteq R$ \ $\left\{0 \right\}$ such that:

There exists finite $X \subseteq S$ such that for every $y \in S$, there is an $a \in R$ such that $ay \in X$ or $ya \in X$?

I've been unable to find an example and I'm starting to wonder if such an $S$ cannot exist.

Comment: Well, just let $0\in X$ and you can take $a=0$

Comment: @MarcoFlores: $S$ does not contain $0$, and $X \subset S$.

Comment: I knew I was missing something :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $R=\prod \limits_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z_2}$. $R$ is a ring with a single unit. We let $S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots)\in R: x_1=1\}$, and let $X=(1,0,0,\cdots)$. Clearly for any $y \in S$, $y~.(1,0,0,\cdots)=(1,0,0,\dots)\in X$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks

Comment: @M10687, thanks. May I know what was the motivation behind this question?

Comment: I was looking at certain topologies one can put on arbitrary rings and for the specific one I was looking at, this question was related to existence of infinite compact sets. Your answer proves that such sets do exist.

Comment: Hmmm, somehow I think this maybe related is related to the fact that arbitrary product of compact sets is compact. Or maybe there's nothing ...

Comment: That is a good point, each $\mathbb{Z}_2$ would be trivially compact in any topology. Regardless this example was enlightening for me.